# Force St_split() to return geometries in specific pattern

Tags: postgis, postgresql, splitting

I'm Using PostGIS `st_split()` to split a polygon geometry by a linestring. Then I use `st_dump()` to return each of the splitted geometry and it is working fine. But the issue is I want to force st_dump() to return in a specific pattern. For example if the line is vertical, return left geometry first and then right as shown below.

[image]

While if the linestring is horizantal, return upper geometry first then lower geometry.

[image]

Currently, it return geometry randomly.

Below is the snippet which return me splitted geometries

```
SELECT  ((ST_Dump(ST_Split(circle, line))).geom) As wkt
FROM (SELECT 
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(73.3864598921383 33.8985381624948,73.3962348946526 33.8646669883339)',4326) As line,
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((73.3733940124512 33.8850949267837,73.4058380126953 33.8936448555238,73.41313362121582 33.87818310806669,73.377857208252 33.8708431412792,73.3735656738281 33.8772567393002,73.3733940124512 33.8850949267837))',4326) As circle) As foo;
```

Comment: I think ordering by distance from point made by corner of geometry could do the job. Please paste in your code so I can try to modify it for you.

Comment: @Jendrusk.. Please have a look. I've updated the question.

Comment: thx i'll look at this tommorrow :)

Comment: @Jendrusk.. Hey man! a day has past. Please have a look.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite busy now... I'll try by the weekend, but 4 now little prompt - you have to tread your query as subquery and select from it objects ordered by distance from corner - needed functions are ST_MakePoint(ST_XMin(geom), ST_YMax(geom)) and ST_Distance(). Other way is ordering by sum of coordinates 'order by (ST_x(geom)+ST_y(geom))' or 'order by ST_x(geom), ST_y(geom))'

Comment: Hey man! A week has passed. Please give any feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

You've got few ways to do this:

1. Draw the point in upper left corner of geometry and order by distance from this point
2. Order by added coordinates of upper left vertex of both geometries

   ```
   Select * from  
     (  
     SELECT  ((ST_Dump(ST_Split(circle, line))).geom) As wkt  
     FROM  
       (  
       SELECT   
       ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(73.3864598921383 33.8985381624948,73.3962348946526 33.8646669883339)',4326) As line,  
       ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((73.3733940124512 33.8850949267837,73.4058380126953 33.8936448555238,73.41313362121582 33.87818310806669,73.377857208252 33.8708431412792,73.3735656738281 33.8772567393002,73.3733940124512 33.8850949267837))',4326) As circle
       ) As foo  
     ) as aaa  
   order by st_xmin(aaa.wkt), st_ymax(aaa.wkt)
   ```
3. Order by X of coordinates then by y of coordinates of both geometries

   ```
   Select * from  
     (  
     SELECT  ((ST_Dump(ST_Split(circle, line))).geom) As wkt  
     FROM  
       (  
       SELECT   
       ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(73.3864598921383 33.8985381624948,73.3962348946526 33.8646669883339)',4326) As line,  
       ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((73.3733940124512 33.8850949267837,73.4058380126953 33.8936448555238,73.41313362121582 33.87818310806669,73.377857208252 33.8708431412792,73.3735656738281 33.8772567393002,73.3733940124512 33.8850949267837))',4326) As circle
       ) As foo  
     ) as aaa  
   order by st_xmin(aaa.wkt), st_ymax(aaa.wkt)
   ```

Comment: Those SQL examples are identical.